S parameter for transformer
Transformer is a two port system, I try to use simulation tool to find the s parameters for transformer.
Here is my questions:

How to accurately measure the s parameters for S11,S12,S21,S22. I find the website talking about this, but I'm not sure which is correct or not.
https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/s-parameters-of-a-real-transformer/

Should I connect one side to GND when I measure these four s parameters? like below




Yes, you should connect one side to GND.

@StefanWyss Could you explain it more detail? thanks

GND is nothing more than one port. The other one is signal. You need 2 ports for a 2 port measurement.
